# Linear or superficial expansion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I add only the text of the exercise below but I not ask the solution of the exercise.

> You want to thread an aluminum ring onto a steel bar. To $10.00 °C$ the inner diameter $D$ of the ring is $4.000$ cm and that of the bar is $4.040$ cm. a) In order for the ring to slip on, will it have to be heated
> or cooled? Explain the reason. b) Calculate the temperature of the ring at the time you manage to
> insert it on the bar. The bar remains at $10.00 °C$.

The picture of the exercise is this:

[image]

**My question**:

If I consider the gray colored tube of Aluminum ($\mathrm{Al}$) and section it, it looks to me from the drawing to get a perforated disk rather than a wire ring like the picture below:

[image]

From my point of view, I believe that I have a better approximation by using the surface dilation

$$\Delta A\simeq 2\lambda A_0\Delta T$$

law rather the linear one

$$\Delta D = \lambda D_0\Delta T$$

because I think it is approximately better than the linear one.

> Is my observation correct or is it numerically better to use the linear dilatation law by considering the ring as a wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both equations are linear approximations to the strain and to the expansion behavior vs temperature.  So they are equallly valid in the limit of small strains and small temperature differences.  There is no rational basis for choosing one over the other.

Comment: Hi, and thank you very much for your answer. I know that generally there is an experimental law (linear dilatation) that $\Delta L=\lambda L_0\Delta T$, but for the area and the volume I have an approximation relation neclecting the terms with $O(\lambda^2)\approx 0$ (for example for the area). +1

Comment: The linear dilation  law is also approximate.  Other strain measures, such as logarithmic, will give a slightly different result, although its linear approximation will be the same.

Comment: I have solved the exercise with the $\Delta A=2\lambda A_0\Delta T$, but the right solution on my book it to use the $\Delta D = \lambda D_0\Delta T $. Do will change it something if I adopt the $\Delta A=2\lambda A_0\Delta T$?

Comment: The answer should come out the same

Comment: I know $T_0=10 °C$ but there is, if I not remember wrong, a bit difference of the final temperature $T$ but not is the same.

Comment: To linear terms in the strain, the difference in the final temperature is insignificant.